# Dual boot, shared SSD - change to dual boot, separate ssd

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, ssd

I use a dual boot system Ubuntu/Windows. Windows for gaming only, Ubuntu for serious work. The OS's share one SSD: Ubuntu on /dev/sda5, Ext4 partition and Windows on /dev/sda4, ntsf partition. In addition one separate SSD /dev/nvme0n1p1, ntsf, shared, to shuffle files and images between the two OS's (but mostly used for storing large windows game files). This setup has been running merrily for quite a while. After Win 11 upgrade there has risen a need for a separate windows drive, certain games won't run from shared drive. There lies my question: If I delete partition /dev/sda4, re-format to ext4. Shut down the computer, Install a new SSD and re-install windows on the new drive - Will the Grub boot loader recognise the new drive after reboot or just boot straight into Ubuntu?
The uefi/boot CSM is disabled, secure boot is set to other OS and boot option 1 is set to Ubuntu on "old" SSD. I would love to have the same boot loader option as before, with Ubuntu as priority and Windows as second option when all is done.

Comment: Did you install/upgrade Windows 11 without activating secureboot? Grub don't detect the new Windows 11 installation you have to run `grub-update` or if it isn't avail `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` expect your Uefi starts only windows then you have to live boot and chroot to your Ubuntu partition and install grub again

Comment: Even if sda is a SSD, your NVMe drive is faster. Often better to have operating system you use most or need speed for games on NVMe drive. Grub will dual boot Windows on separate drive if bitlocker & fast start up are off. Note that Windows updates may turn fast start up back on. I prefer to have each install on separate drives, normally if drives are about same speed. If using both a lot, then both installs on fastest drive & some or most of data on slower drive as accessed less. Configuration will depend on your use pattern.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying some of these points I have not thought of. I have not done any corrective measures yet, waiting for some hardware to arrive pr. mail later in the week. Will post when I have result, until then I'll hack it :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: I am grateful for all the help, hints and links I get here and I will use the wisdom shared. The problem now is that I live in such a remote area I am dependent on mail service for hardware delivery and the dispatch has been slow, I am still waiting. I want to have everything in place before I start and will report back as soon I have finished upgrading with full report on proceeds.

Comment: OK guys. By following good advice and instructions I have succeeded in re-building hardware and software configuration on my computer. The OS's now each resides on their separate NVMe SSD and grub works perfect. Windows gave the most headache. Not booting but I had to go into Ubuntu to download drivers and stuff to get windows to get-go. Ubuntu just took everything in stride and reliable as ever. Everything up and running, just have to do some hacking to ease everything into groove and all is hunky dory :). Thank You everyone for taking interest, bless you all!

Comment: That's great. We'd like it if you were to write up what you did as an answer so that future searchers looking  for a solution to the same issues might find it. (Comments are like mayflies, they don't last around here.)